# Unitialized Constant Xaaron::Group::GroupsRole

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

So I am not understanding this error. I am trying to do the following:

```
module Xaaron
  class GroupsRoles < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :groups
    belongs_to :roles
  end
end

module Xaaron
  class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
    extend FriendlyId
    friendly_id :group_name, use: [:slugged, :finders, :history]

    has_many :groups_roles
    has_many :roles, :through => :groups_roles

    validates :group_name, presence: true, uniqueness: true

  end
end

module Xaaron
  class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
    extend FriendlyId
    friendly_id :role_name, use: [:slugged, :finders, :history]

    has_many :groups_roles
    has_many :groups, :through => :groups_roles

    validates :role_name, presence: true
    validates_uniqueness_of :role_name

  end
end
```

Its petter basic I am trying to create a join table using models and associations, by saying that roles has many groups and groups has many roles. this way I can assign many roles to many groups and vice versa.

I should also be able to get all groups a role belongs to and all roles a group has.

So the migration:

```
class GroupsAndRoles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :xaaron_groups_roles do |t|
      t.belongs_to :groups
      t.belongs_to :roles
      t.integer :group_id
      t.integer :role_id
    end
  end
end
```

*One of the things I am a bit confused by, since this is an engine - should I be referencing the  `xaaron_groups` table (as thats what the table is called), or can I do `groups` and it knows what I am talking about?*

When I go into `rails c` and do, after creating a group.

```
g = Xaaron::Group.first
g.roles #=> I should get []
```

I get: `NameError: uninitialized constant Xaaron::Group::GroupsRole`

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's looking for the singular form of GroupsRoles (GroupsRole) and your class is named with the plural, so it can't find it. Rails will automatically look for the singular class name.

Rename your class and it should work.